# Switch Participants in and out of Google Hangout

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, google-hangouts

I need to be able to switch participants in and out of a video conference from say a database of online users. I've been working with Hangout since they are the only open source video conferencing service I know. I know in Hangout you can get an extension to 'kick' someone, but I can't seem to find it in their API. Does anyone know how I can kick and add people either automatically, or manually? I want to ideally do it in Ruby, and I've tried with Python since Hangout is in python, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the api, you can only change who is in the broadcast but not in the actual Hangout (ie no kick API.) This functionality is the same is in the builtin "Cameraman" app for Hangout On Air. Read more about the api at [setParticipantBroadcast](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.setParticipantInBroadcast) on the Developer Site.